# Is it possible to override the background of a parent element to show the background of a grandparent element?

Tags: css, background, overriding, parallax

Suppose I have the following:

```
<div id="grandparent" style="background:some-image">
 <div id="parent" style="background-color:white">
  <div id="child" style="something">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use CSS in #child to override the white background from #parent and show the image from #grandparent?

(This is for a parallax scrolling effect where simply removing #parent is not an option)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DIVs don't act like masks in photoshop. But what you CAN do is to imitate this effect by placing the same background image for both grandparent and child by using `background-position: fixed` and adding corresponding background-offset or, if you prefere, by using JS to dynamicaly recalculate child background offset depending on it's position relative to grandparent - it's not so hard as it sounds.

Also, there is CSS3 bachround positioning, like this `background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 10px);`